# Is there a specific reason for having a very short window for passengers to get to the boarding gate before closing it?

Tags: air-travel, airports, ryanair

I am not a frequent traveler but it's been like this with all the flights I have been on.
Here is the most recent example:

Below is my boarding pass

[image]

As you can see Gate Closes at 20:20

Here is the departures board at 18:32, clearly it says that they will announce the boarding gate at 20:10  ?!

[image]

I was hoping they will do that earlier but at 19:41 it's still the same

[image]

In fact they announced it at 20:11 but since I was freaking out and had to leg it to the gate I didn't have the time to take a photo.

You might think 9 minutes is enough, well below are the times required to reach the gates from the closest place to them

[image]
[image]

And that's for a healthy young person, no way my grandmother could be able to be at the gates within 9 minutes.

Is there a specific reason? it's not like they allocate the gate dynamically! The staff must have known about the gate hours ago as I don't expect the pilot to drive the airplane from the garage to the gate within 9 minutes?

Comment: The late gate announcement is normally caused by the incoming plane being delayed, so they don't know where it'll come in at. Almost certainly they will have closed the gate later than expected too

Comment: @Gagravarr I don't think so, the board never said "Delayed", the flight departed on time, also it was the same with the inbound flight and every other flight I have been on. The maximum window is 20-30 minutes.

Comment: You were flying the passenger-hating RyanAir, so who knows... Generally though late boarding gate announcement is due to late plane arrival, especially at airports where planes pretty much take the next free gate rather than having dedicated ones

Comment: But the plane may have been delayed in arrival.  The ground crew then does a quick turnaround so it can depart on time.  Planes almost never arrive from "the garage"; they normally arrive from another airport with a load of passengers.  The arrival gate can change at any time before the plane actually gets to the gate, even while it is taxiing from the runway, because for example the previous plane in its scheduled gate might be delayed.

Comment: I mostly see this for low-cost airlines. In that case, most passengers will have been processed before the aircraft even touches the ground. The gate will already be closed when passengers from the previous flight finish to disembark. So yes, they can and do change the gate at the last minute. And it puts pressure on the passengers to all show up at the same time. It's all part of an effort to minimise turn-around time and reduce costs, even at the expense of comfort.

Comment: Long-haul flights from legacy airlines will have more stable gates announced in advance, with the aircraft sitting at the gate for longer times before passengers arrive.

Comment: @Relaxed makes an excellent point.  Short turnaround times are an important part of the low-cost airline business model, since the airline pays more to the airport if the plane spends a longer time parked at the gate.

Comment: Also, in your pictures, only Ryanair and Easyjet (both low-cost airlines) use a gate that's 7-8 min away, again possibly a deliberate inconvenience for passengers willing to trade comfort for price. Other airlines have gates closer to the entrance and presumably pay a premium for better service from the airport.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33107/discussion-on-question-by-joulupukki-is-there-a-specific-reason-for-having-a-ver).

Comment: @Relaxed Amazingly, at least one of the flights shown in the pictures here was an Emirates flight to Dubai and it still said that the gate wouldn't be announced until 45 minutes before the scheduled push-back time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Airports at which gates are announced late normally have a hall with shops and restaurants from which the piers with the gates can be reached without any additional security/passport checks. Nearby the gates, there tend to be no shops (but possibly some vending machines).

Announcing the gates late thus helps the airport with making revenue - the passengers stay in the area with the shops until the very last minute. Also, last-minute gate changes are easy as when this happens, no passenger should have the old incorrect gate in mind.

While many fellow posters mentioned that late gate announcements happens mostly for low cost airlines, the photos by the OP also show a couple of BA flights with late gate announcements. BA is certainly not a low cost airline. I've noticed that UK airports tend to announce gates late, and often, the gate will be listed on flightaware.com many minutes before it is announced on the airport screens.

Comment: (+1) The OP also mentioned the time to takes to reach the gate. Apparently, BA flights have gates that are close-by and are still announced a bit earlier (up to 45 min before departure vs. 25).

Comment: @Relaxed Indeed! There are some BA flights that seem to be announced a bit earlier. What I just find striking is that the BA flight to London City on the OP's photo is scheduled to only be announced 30 minutes before departure. Now flights to LCY aren't the ones that tend to be low-cost.

Comment: GLA or EDI to LCY are very much business flights. Passengers typically have everything ready, 1 carry on item etc, so loading is much more efficient. I would class them as pretty low cost though. I usually go to LCY with BA when I to visit London as it's cheaper than train or EasyJet

Answer (score 37):

Normal airlines will have a period of "Boarding" before "Last call": Ryanair's first call is also a "Last call". The gate probably actually closed at something closer to 20:40. In other words, the window isn't as short as they pretend, but they want to put pressure on the customers.

Comment: To airlines, as with most businesses, time is money.

Answer (score 21):

I mostly see this for low-cost airlines. In that case, most passengers will have been processed before the aircraft even touches the ground. The gate will already be closed when passengers from the previous flight finish to disembark. So yes, they can and do change the gate at the last minute.

But in some cases, it seem to go beyond that. Announcing late puts pressure on the passengers to all show up at the same time and occurs systematically in some places (e.g. low-cost terminal at Schiphol airport near Amsterdam). And at AMS, the gate really does not open before it's announced so it only stays open for 15-20 min tops. It's all part of an effort to minimise turn-around time and reduce costs, even at the expense of comfort.

By contrast, bar some unexpected issue, at Schiphol's other terminals, gates for long-haul flights from legacy airlines will be announced well in advance and stay open for a longer period of time. In that case, the aircraft will typically already be at the gate when you arrive, which is not the case for low-cost operations.

In this particular case, it seems that [Glasgow airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Airport) has a dedicated “low-cost” pier and I note that only Ryanair and Easyjet have flights departing from gates that are 7-8 min away from the place where you took the pictures.

I suspect some airports charge these low-cost carriers lower fees to keep their traffic but deliberately inconvenience passengers so that the low-cost pier only appeals to people willing to trade comfort for price, while other airlines keep using the more expensive regular pier and have gates that do not require so much walking.

Comment: That was the case with atleast one low-fare airline in one European airport. They actually paid less for airport services and it was a royal pain in the lower back for passengers, who also had to pay additional fees as the airport to board their flight.

Comment: @Egil How does that possibly pass the standard European conventions regarding advertising the price the customer actually pays?

Comment: @Louis That situation was fixed in beginning of this year, after existing for some 3 years. Passengers had to pay a fee for the security check, which all airlines except one included in the ticket price. So the dispute went on for years the airport blaming the airline for not including the fee in the ticket price, and the airline claiming their contract with the airport (at the time) said nothing about any such fee, untill their contract expired.

Comment: wrt GLA: it's a dedicated "low-cost" *domestic* pier: they use the same gates as everyone else for the international stuff.

Comment: There's a *fee* for the security check? Well, I'd like to opt out of the security check then, and save a few bucks.

Comment: @DanHenderson If only that worked. Unfortunately, such fees aren't really uncommon. All U.S. flights have them, but they're included in the advertised ticket price.

Comment: I recently flew domestically from Glasgow and even my BA flight's gate was only announced about ten minutes before boarding began. Ironically, there were several shops and cafes between the departure lounge and the gate and they must be doing terrible business because everybody has to walk straight past them.

Comment: @reirab Unavoidable fees have to be included in the advertised price in the EU, too, and have been for several years, so the claims Egil makes must be from some time ago.

Answer (score 7):

If your problem is that your grandmother cannot walk quickly, consider asking for Boarding Assistance for her and her companion.

Even the budget airlines have a plan for providing boarding assistance. Sometimes it includes a special bus to take you to the plane (not the gate) and a special lift to put you into the plane by the back door, before any of the other customers are allowed on.

In theory only 1 companion is permitted, but my family had success with 1 companion and 1 child accompanying the person who had recently had knee surgery…

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, boarding gates will stay open (for a reasonable amount of time) until all passenger who got boarding passes come for boarding. Several times, I would arrive as late as 15-20 minutes past boarding time.

I don't advise you to be late for boarding on purpose, but I don't think your grandmother should not travel with RyanAir because she can't run fast enough. They will wait for her. Denying boarding to someone who has trouble walking (or just went to the toilet for 5 minutes) would result in endless influx of customer complaints, ruining the business.

Comment: Since when has Ryanair cared about an endless stream of customer complaints?

Comment: Far more important: There is no luggage allowed to be on the plane, if the owner is not on the plane!
 So if they deny you to board because you are 15min late, they would actually have to unload the luggage from the cargo bay, find your luggage, remove it, load the rest on the plane again. 
The airline would have to pay the airport for this service, and it will take time and delay the flight, which might then be also more expensive for the airline.
So if you have luggage checked in, it is almost always a lot cheaper for the airline to just let you board.

Comment: @Josef very good info!

Answer (score 4):

In aviation everything is optimised to the maximum, as long as it doesn't undermine safety, and Ryanair is especially notorious for this.

Most of the time the planes come down, unload cargo/pax, refuel, sometimes crews change, then in shortest possible time they load in passengers and cargo, then fly away. All that is done on a really tight schedule. That's why passengers are advised to be at the gate before the boarding starts.

As for late announcement - well, we're all human, including the people announcing things in aieports.

Source: work experience at an airport

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the OP's question, late announcement is a systematic occurence or a deliberate policy in some cases (e.g. the low-cost terminal at AMS), there must be a reason for it.

Comment: @Relaxed My bad, I missed the point about systematic occurance. Still I beleive the reason is (over)optimization. And, perhaps, sub-par management.

Comment: In Schiphol Amsterdam, the low cost pier is not that large, the lounge to wait is near it and it is not more than a few minutes walking distance. The only difficulty was when there was a security station between the lounge and the pier. That has been removed now and the walk is now straight forward, (and you can even use the screens close to the pier rather than those in the lounge.)

Comment: @Willeke The distance may not be that large but it's made deliberately uncomfortable compared to the rest of the airport. For example, there is no way to wait at the gate, which is announced at the last minute and the website [makes it clear that it's deliberate](http://www.schiphol.nl/Reizigers/OpSchiphol/CheckinControles/VertrekVanafHOfMgates.htm). And judging from the map (I haven't used it in quite a while), it seems that there is still a security inspection between the lounge and the gate for non-Schengen low-cost flights.

Comment: Last time I used it, August 2015, the security post machines and barriers were moved to the side of the area and covered.

Comment: No, there are airports where gate announcements are systematically late. I recently flew BA from Heathrow to Glasgow and back; the gate at Heathrow was announced about 15 minutes before boarding and at Glasgow, it was about 10 minutes. Even international flights from Heathrow often only announce the gate half an hour or so before boarding begins. In contrast, I've had layovers of 4+ hours in the US where the gate of my connecting flight has been on the screens as soon as I've got through immigration.

Comment: I am used to Schiphol (Amsterdam Airport) where usually the gates are announced 12 hours (or even more) before departure, but there is a risk the gate will be changed.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to all of the great answers above, one thing worth saying about low cost carriers in general (and Ryanair specifically) is that minimising *turnaround time is absolutely **crucial*** to their business. While we don't know exactly how much Ryanair's fleet of 737 aircraft cost to run per hour, it's a *lot* (an upper bound would probably be on the order of $11k USD per hour as [you can hire one for that much](http://www.privatefly.com/private-jets/large-airliner-hire/Boeing-737-300.html)), we *do* know that it's going to be earning them exactly zero money sat on the ground.

All airlines are subject to, more or less, the same fuel costs, use essentially the same aircraft (which are always chosen based on their *economic* efficiency for a given route, which is not necessarily the same thing as their *temporal* efficiency -- in Japan you find all-economy 747s doing short haul, [for example](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13150/what-are-the-benefits-of-long-haul-airplanes-servicing-regional-routes/13152#13152)) and have essentially the same (legally mandated) service costs. *Turnaround time is basically the only thing that is left for them to compete on*.

There has been much academic analysis done about minimising turnaround time; e.g. [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40622-014-0062-0) article details how operations research has been used to look at the problem. Aviation throws up many interesting problems like this -- [several of which are](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.itasoftware.com/en//pdf/ComplexityofArlineTravelPlanning_Carl_Sep-03.pdf) [NP hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_hard), and Boeing [themselves](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_4_08/pdfs/AERO_Q408_article03.pdf) have produced a document detailing how a time saving on the order of minutes can result in the difference between making a *lot* of money on an airline route and being faced with some *very* large shortfalls to make up. *Heck*, a quick google shows up [this Masters' thesis](http://www.staffs.ac.uk/schools/business/resits/postgrad/OperationsMgmtCaseStudy-Ryanir.pdf) looking at Rynair's profitability and turnaround time. If you'll forgive me selectively quoting the relevant bits about **just how crucial** turnaround time is to Rynair, they're quite telling:

> By taking about half the [turnaround] time of the larger airlines like British Airways (BA) or Lufthansa, Ryanair’s planes made an average of nine trips per day as against the average six of larger airlines.
>
> [...]
>
> No other low-cost airline managed to replicate Ryanair’s results. According to analysts, its “cost per available seat mile” (the yardstick used by the airline industry to measure costs) was 30% lower than the average for Europe’s major airlines, and its productivity - as measured by the number of passengers per employee - was 40% higher. As a result, Ryanair could break even when its planes were just over half-full.

I would say that the fact that Ryanair does not tell you which gate to go to ahead of time is because they themselves do not necessarily know. When you add in the fact that Ryanair pays tiny landing fees to most airports (negotiated on 15-20 year terms), it's entirely likely that their gate -- which they might want to squeeze in around other, longer operators -- may be necessarily uncertain until it is clear what has happened elsewhere in the airport.

What's *far* more important to them is, frankly, that *the aircraft* gets to *a* gate and leaves with some (not necessarily all!) passengers *as soon as possible*. I'm afraid that, as far as they're concerned, you and your grandmother's inability to get to the gate on time would just be another willing sacrifice on the altar of capitalism.

Answer (score 1):

I saw in a documentary that the reason is commercial. Many European airports want you to be on the center, near shopping area, so you can spend more. They get much money from passengers. In US airports are public, so they exploit less passengers.

For such reason, they try to keep security queue as short as possible, and try to get as quick as possible passengers on the central part of airport.

But delaying embarkation has also costs, so you get the time when the will announce the gate, and usually around 45 minutes before departure.

If you look around or you check on some other online sources, you may see the gate before it is published on airport screens. Sometime it is also on the ticket.

Just I found confusing that now you may find boarding time and not departure time on your ticket (or on screens), so it is more difficult to find your flight on the list.

Comment: Although this probably is one of the factors determining how long in advance the gate gets shown, it depend very much on the airport. In the rush hour in peak season, almost every flight is somewhat late (and low-cost ones especially so) and most of the gates are occupied. It's not that useful to be told which gate to go to two hours in advance, just to have the gate changed later (possibly multiple times). Regarding boarding/departure times, that's simply because there still are people who will only go to the gate at the scheduled departure time, find it closed, and throw a fit.

Comment: @TooTea: low costs tend not to use bridges, so gates is less then a problem. Available gates could be a problem, but try on non-peak hours, when you see many free gates, and your gate already being served, but no notice on departure screens. The 45 minutes are still in place. And you may still get gate change later (so it is still announced as the program, not when the gates is "booked")

Comment: It's still a "boarding gate", regardless of whether it leads to a jetway or a bus. And it's presumably simpler for the airport to have 45 minutes programmed into the system and used all day than to dynamically adjust that interval during the day based on demand. Of course it can always change (if the previous plane occupying the gate is delayed for any reason, etc.).

Comment: @TooTea: Yeah, but it was introduced (and you find mostly) on the very commercial airports, where all is designed to make passenger spend more (they estimates 40-70 euro per passenger). There could be operating reasons, but they are big commercial entities, and this started because of commercial interest, and with adapted airports with large central areas. BTW it seems this is done in London Heathrow, Bruxelles, Zurich, but not in Amsterdam where I had experienced more "air parking problems".